# How to custom Bootstrap grid height?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Why this Bootstrap grid has the height 591.067 ?
Where did this height come from?

```css
.main-post {
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    border: 1px solid #D8D8D8;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
}

.main-post .post-categories {
    margin-bottom: 10px
}

.main-post h3 {
    margin: 0 0 10px;
    color: #777;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    font-weight: bold
}

.main-post .post-author,
.main-post .post-date,
.main-post .post-comments {
    font-size: 12px
}

.main-post img {
    display: block;
    margin: 10px 0;
}

.main-post .post-summary {
    line-height: 1.7;
    color: #888
}

.main-post i {
    color: #999
}
```

```html
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="main-post">
                        <h3 class="post-title">
                            <a href="#">
                                Post Title
                            </a>
                        </h3>
                        <span class="post-author">
                          <i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i>
                          Etsh
                        </span>
                        <span class="post-date">
                        <i class="fa fa-calendar fa-fw"></i>
                          07/2017
                        </span>
                        <span class="post-comments"><i class="fa fa-comments  fa-fw"></i>
                            No comments
                        </span>
                       <img src="http://www.placehold.it/300x300">
                        <p class="post-summary">
                            Test...
                        </p>
                        <hr>
                        <div class="post-categories">
                            <i class="fa fa-tags fa-fw"></i>
                            Categories
                        </div>
                        <p class="post-tags">
                            Tags
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

As you can see in the image I can't get The "Prev" and "Next" buttons below the posts because of this height.

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: try to provide an example which shows the same results. Hard to say based on a screenshot and unrelated code.

Answer (score 0):

Your `.mainpost` has a `margin-bottom: 100px`.

That could be the culprit. Remove that and see what happens. You might need to find a different way to space your posts out. (Search around for flexbox) Without a clearer example it's hard to say though.

Comment: that's what happened when I removed the margin https://ibb.co/dn5sUk
the buttons are stick on the footer